# Proofs using Direct proofs

Tags: discrete-mathematics

im trying to solve the following problem using Direct proof method

Consider two integers $a$ and $b$, with $a≠0$. We say that $a$ divides $b$, and we write $a\mid b$, iff there exists an integer $m$ such that $b=am$. Now, consider three integers $a, b$ and $c$, with $a≠0$ and $b≠0$; show that if $a\mid b$ and $b\mid c$ then $a \mid c$.

Can someone else explain how to do this problem using direct proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $a \mid b$ and $b \mid c$, there are integers $m,n$ such that $b = ma$ and $c = nb$. Now $c = nb = nma = (nm)a$, thus there exists an integer $mn$ that gives $c$ when multiplied by $a$. It follows that $a \mid c$.